# Given login/signUp code by Parse.com, has binary operator error

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am making SignUp/SignIn pages with watching youtube video.

He makes these pages with parseUI,

In his video, there is no error, but I get an error which is

"binary operator "|" cannot be applied  to two 'PFLoginFields' operands" (It is checked where in my code down there. )

I checked in parse.com, parse example code is exactly same code with his.

So my Question is

How can I fix this code to work properly?

or Is there any other Binary operator I can use instead of ||?

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class NewResisterVC: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {

var logInViewController : PFLogInViewController = PFLogInViewController()
var signUpViewController : PFSignUpViewController = PFSignUpViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {


  /////////// HERE IS A PROBELM /////////////////
        self.logInViewController.fields = (PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.DismissButton)
       ////////////////////////////////////////// 


        var loginLogoTitle = UILabel()
        loginLogoTitle.text = "bany"

        self.logInViewController.logInView!.logo = loginLogoTitle

        self.logInViewController.delegate = self

        var signUpLogoTitle = UILabel()
        signUpLogoTitle.text = "bany"

        self.signUpViewController.signUpView!.logo = signUpLogoTitle

        self.signUpViewController.delegate = self

        self.logInViewController.signUpController = self.signUpViewController
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK: Parse Login

func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String, password: String) -> Bool {

    if(!username.isEmpty || !password.isEmpty) {
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }

}

func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didFailToLogInWithError error: NSError?) {
    print("Fail to login")
}



//MARK: Parse Sign Up

func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didSignUpUser user: PFUser) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didFailToSignUpWithError error: NSError?) {
    print("fail to sign up...")
}

func signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController) {
    print("User dismissed sign up")
}

// mark: Actions

@IBAction func simpleAction(send: AnyObject) {

    self.presentViewController(self.logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guy in video is using xcode 6 with swift 1.2, you are using xcode 7 with swift 2.0. Syntax has changed, you have to rewrite this line like this:

```
self.logInViewController.fields = [PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword,
    PFLogInFields.LogInButton, PFLogInFields.SignUpButton,
    PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten, PFLogInFields.DismissButton]
```

Also note that you don't need to write typename prefix when assigning to variable:

```
self.logInViewController.fields = [.UsernameAndPassword, .LogInButton,
    .SignUpButton, .PasswordForgotten, .DismissButton]
```

Comment: Great answer! Fixes the problem. +1 from me